# How to import/consume ES6 modules which are in .js extension with --experimental-module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

My `mjs` files can import other `mjs` file but cannot import `js` file in the chain of imports. In the following example imagine that kale.js is a 3rd party library e.g. `lodash-es/isObject.js`
e.g.

```
// apple.mjs
import {banana} from './banana.mjs';
```

..and

```
// banana.mjs
import {kale} from './kale.js';
export function banana() {};
```

and `kale.js` is

```
// kale.js
export function kale() {};
export function kite() {}
```

I get following error:-

> $ node --experimental-modules ./test/apple.mjs (node:389272)
>   ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
>   SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named
>   'kale'
>       at checkComplete (internal/loader/ModuleJob.js:75:27)
>       at moduleJob.linked.then (internal/loader/ModuleJob.js:58:11)
>       at

Tried custom resolve function but still no luck:

```
import url from 'url';
import path from 'path';


const JS_EXTENSIONS = new Set(['.js', '.mjs']);

export default function resolve(specifier, parentModuleURL, defaultResolve ) {
  console.log('resolving '+specifier);
  if (/^\.{0,2}[/]/.test(specifier) !== true && !specifier.startsWith('file:')) {
    return defaultResolve(specifier, parentModuleURL);
  }
  const resolved = new url.URL(specifier, parentModuleURL);
  const ext = path.extname(resolved.pathname);
  if (!JS_EXTENSIONS.has(ext)) {
    throw new Error(
      `Cannot load file with non-JavaScript file extension ${ext}.`);
  }
  return {
    url: resolved.href,
    format: 'esm'
  };
}
```

and I am running it like this:

```
node --experimental-modules --loader ./custom-loader.mjs apple.mjs
```

node version v8.9.1

I get following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at createDynamicModule (internal/loader/ModuleRequest.js:43:15)
    at setExecutor (internal/loader/ModuleWrap.js:40:23)
    at file:///C:/Users/user/projs/dev/my-project-js/test/es2015/test/kale.js:8:36
```

UPDATE --- using `@std/esm` approach as per the answer

All code is here https://github.com/yogeshgadge/mjs-mixed-loaders.git

This is what worked:

```
//index.js
require = require("@std/esm")(module,{"esm":"js"});
module.exports = require("./apple.mjs").default;
```

Then I run it as below (and now I am eating kale:)):-

```
$ node index.js
eating kale with some lodash
```

`package.json` approach did not work.

```
$ node -r @std/esm apple.mjs
C:\Users\myuser\projs\github\mjs-in-harmony\node_modules\lodash-es\isObject.js:31
export default isObject;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
```

Comment: You should not use ES6 `export` syntax in a `.js` file. Just rename it to `kale.mjs`.

Comment: I am demonstrating other ES6 modules which are widely named as `.js` not in my control. e.g. `lodash-es/isObject.js` which does `export default isObject;`

Comment: @Bergi I have updated my question title and the clarification.

Comment: I think lodash still requires transpilation. Alternatively you could try opening an issue in their repo asking them to rename their files to work with node.js natively. The last option seems to be a [custom resolve hook](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolve_hook) that tells node the lodash `.js` file is a ES module regardless of its file extension.

Comment: Loader hooks seems like a better deal - thank you - I will play with it and post it here fi works. Opening an issue with lodash or so many libraries that have been bundling ES5 tranpiled code with ES6 import/export will require them to change their extension to .mjs. Ideally that will be lovely.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to [publish native ES6 modules backwards compatible with Node <8.5.0 require](https://medium.com/@dandv/publishing-native-es-modules-with-node-v8-5-0-730736e0f612). Check for example [local-iso-dt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-iso-dt#usage). Also, lodash in particular has published [lodash-es](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3762#issuecomment-383326889) (not something I'd recommend).

Comment: @DanDascalescu I think you are missing the point in question. It is about interoperability and even that worked in (node 8x) when the level is only 2 levels deep but fails from mjs->mjs->js(es6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the [@std/esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) loader with `"@std/esm":"cjs"` options:

- Install `@std/esm` (`npm i --save @std/esm`)
- Add `"@std/esm":"cjs"` to your package.json
- Now `node -r @std/esm apple.mjs` will load successfully

Comment: Had to use `require = require("@std/esm")(module,{"esm":"js"});` packahe.json did not work

Comment: @bhantol Your repo use is different than the example you outlined in stackoverflow. I commented on tweaks in the repo.

Comment: Trying to get `node -r @std/esm apple.mjs` to work. I updated the repo. Only `{"es": "js"}` seems to work and not the answer you posted. Any reason why ? Or how can I get your option working as well.